# CSS : Label / Textbox not displaying inline correctly

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I this dropdown:

```
@* POLICY ORGANISATION *@    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="diagnosticMode" class="control-label col-xs-2">Policy Organisation:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <select id="DD1" name="PolicyOrganisation" class="btn btn-default">
                <option value="-1">Select</option>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PolicyOrgs)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which is being styled with

```
select {
width: 300px !important;
border: 1px solid gray !important;
outline: medium none !important;
height: 30px !important;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

label{
white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

Which looks like the above:
[image: Image of label being behind the drop-down box]

My Issue: How do I get the two elements to display side by side so that the end text of "policy organization:" is not clipped.

What Ive Tried so far :

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: have you tried adding a `margin-left` to the select element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is right if u want to show it side by side but your text is too large thats why it is under the box.

try that code below

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="diagnosticMode" class="control-label col-xs-3">Policy Organisation:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select id="DD1" name="PolicyOrganisation" class="btn btn-default">
            <option value="-1">Select</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PolicyOrgs)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i did make col-xs-3 for the text and for the select col-xs-9

check that Demo [here](http://www.bootply.com/LfhuzH2kld#)

Answer (score 1):

Add class  'controls form-inline' to the the div  
      which is the bootstrap css class to make controls in line .

try this one

```
<div class="form-group controls form-inline ">
    <label for="diagnosticMode" class="control-label col-xs-2">Policy Organisation:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <select id="DD1" name="PolicyOrganisation" class="btn btn-default">
            <option value="-1">Select</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PolicyOrgs)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the label float left. That's compatible with most browsers:

```
label {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 6px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

I have put `line-height: 30px;` for the line to be aligned and `margin-right` to have some separation. Also all the labels will be aligned to right.

You can regulate the labels width changing the `with:` value.

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wmjdfp8p/).